# I need a solution to starting Slick 2D/LWJGL Java project via command line. Help?

Tags: java, batch-file, launcher, lwjgl

Currently I am starting my Slick 2D application via this batch file-

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib -Xms512m -Xmx512m -jar myapp.jar %1
```

Where lib is the folder that contains the LWJGL/Slick libraries and myapp.jar is my application.

Although this is easy and effective I want to be able not to have to run a script all the time and actually create a java .jar to do this.

So my question is, how would I 'convert' this batch script into Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any -D command line arguments can be set via `java.lang.System.setProperty`. But the memory parameters can't be set from inside a JVM as far as I know. Therefore, there is no way to do what you want.

Instead you could generate e.g. a Windows executable with [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/). Such a wrapper should be able to set all JVM arguments. But in the end the situation is similar to the script. You have some kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Why you would want Java code for this is beyond me as that creates *exactly* the same problem for you again – namely running your startup Java program that then starts another Java program; you'd be at the same point as before.

However, you don't need to create a JAR in any case. You can stuff all your compiled `.class` files somewhere and set that as the classpath. A JAR is little more than a main class and a classpath bundled into one.

So instead of your invocation above you can then use

```
java ... -cp %USERPROFILE%\Java\MyApp myapp.gui.Main
```

or something like that. Set the classpath with `-cp` and give the main class on the command line instead of the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a program like JarSplice (http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)

You can easily create a jar executable with all needed lib. it works very well